# PHP printing three dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

So, I want to print the following three dimensional array in an HTML table.

```
array ( 'BTC_YACC' => array ( 0 => array ( 'orderNumber' => '3585379', 'type' => 'sell', 'rate' => '0.0001', 'amount' => '128', 'total' => '0.0128', 'date' => '2014-05-18 08:54:37', ), ), )
```

This is what I came up with: (OrderNumber = OrderID).

```
$tableopenorders = "<table><th>OrderID</th><th>Type</th><th>Rate</th><th>Amount</th><th>Total in BTC</th><th>Date placed</th><tr>";

for($element = 0; $element < count($decodedopenorders); $element++) {
    $tableopenorders .= "<tr>";
    for($row = 0; $row < 1; $row++) {
        for ($col = 0; $col < 6; $col++) {
             $tableopenorders .= "<td>".$decodedopenorders[$element][$row][$col]."</td>";
        }   
    }
    $tableopenorders .= "</tr>";
}

$tableopenorders .= "</table>";
```

There's a maximum of "count($decodedopenorders)"  $elements, max. 1 $row and 6 rows in the $decodedopenorders array. The iterator starts a 0, so I used <.

**Why does this not work?**

Comment: why do you need this loop `for($row = 0; $row < 1; $row++)`?

Comment: Orion, I thought it would be useful for structuring the loops.

Comment: Do you know there is a difference between arrays and associative arrays? $a[0] is not the same as $a['someKey'] Also, read the docs for array_values if you insist on accessing them by numeric indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you loop through your arrays you have changed the key to be something other than the typical 0, 1, 2, 3. When you change the key the $decodedopenorders[0] no longer works and instead you would have to call $decodedopenorders['BTC_YACC']; So here is the code I got to work:

```
$decodedopenorders = array ( 
    'BTC_YACC' => array ( 
                     0 => array ( 
                          'orderNumber' => '3585379', 
                          'type' => 'sell', 
                          'rate' => '0.0001', 
                          'amount' => '128', 
                          'total' => '0.0128', 
                          'date' => '2014-05-18 08:54:37') 
                      ) 
                      );
$tableopenorders = "<table><th>OrderID</th><th>Type</th><th>Rate</th><th>Amount</th><th>Total in BTC</th><th>Date placed</th><tr>";

foreach ($decodedopenorders as $element => $value) {
    $tableopenorders .= "<tr>";
    foreach ($decodedopenorders[$element] as $row => $value){
        foreach ($decodedopenorders[$element][$row] as $order) {
           $tableopenorders .= "<td>". $order ."</td>";
             }   
        }
    $tableopenorders .= "</tr>";
    }

    $tableopenorders .= "</table>";

    echo $tableopenorders;
```